# Centralized Codebase with Multiple Websites

Tags: php, nginx, centos, plesk

I have a CentOS 7.1.1503 (Core) server running with Plesk 12.0.18 and Nginx 1.9.4-centos7.15091112.

I am trying to host the codebase for my web-app at `/var/www/vhosts/my-web-app/`

Then I want to host multiple websites on different domains that all use the same codebase, ie `/var/www/vhosts/my-first-website.com/`, `/var/www/vhosts/my-second-website.org/`

`/var/www/vhosts/my-web-app/` doesn't necessarily have to be in `/vhosts/`, I've not done this before.

So really my aim is to direct all requests to `http://www.my-first-website.com` that don't point to a file that already exists to actually be pointed to /var/www/vhosts/my-web-app/index.php where I have a parser that will connect to the right database and deal with the request.

I've tried to use the nginx directives section in my Plesk setup as below:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite .*$ /var/www/vhosts/my-web-app/index.php break;
}
```

But this isn't working, perhaps because the route is already set to `/var/www/vhosts/my-web-app/` and so I am in fact trying to redirect to `/var/www/vhosts/my-first-website.com/var/www/vhosts/my-web-app/index.php`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The web app is written in PHP, I thought it might help to mention that.

Comment: But the issue at hand / what the question is about, is not related to php?

Comment: I don't know enough about server configuration to know whether the fact that it is PHP is relevant or not, I thought it was useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this possible solutions via plesk control panel:

- create domain alias name.
- or create additional domain with same document root as on first domain.